# How to change and maintain multiple color themes at runtime with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like my web app to have different colored themes:

So now I have:

RedTheme.css
BlueTheme.css

And I load each dynamically at runtime. Depending what user selects in his options menu. 
And that works, but I don't like having a separate file for each theme.

Option 1. I'm wondering if there's any way I can do something like:

Theme.css?Theme=Red and then within the css to have it figure out which one to use based on that variable.

Option 2. I'm also wondering if maybe I can do something like inside the CSS to do:

background-color: @themeBackgroundColor

and then somehow set this variable at runtime via javascript or something.

---

If Option 1 and Option 2 are not available, do you have any other suggestions for theming apart from keeping a different file for each theme? b/c maybe I'd like an option where the user can choose custom colors in the future.

Comment: I'm from the future. use css variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use variables in your CSS, have a look at [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), both have client side solutions for this.

To switch styles you could:

- Use a ID attribute for the body like `<body id="red">` and have css prefixed with this id. So `#red myelement.myclass{}` or something. Then switch the ID with javascripts.
- You could have a base CSS file and several theme CSS files on the server side(like gmail does for example) and swap between them with javascript by changing the URL, this would generate a new request in the browser to get the other CSS.
- You could look for or write some small framework of your own which adds the proper styling inside the html itself as a style attribute ([like done here](http://stylebootstrap.info/)), or which adds inline [style elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE) to the html where you define the custom styles and swap them out with javascript.

Any changes to the CSS of elements or HTML by javascript as far as i've seen will trigger the browser to render the page again.

Changing the CSS files on your clients hardisk directly is not possible since javascript does not allow this. You can however change the CSS in the cache or html.

Comment: btw Less/Sass are compile time ... I'm looking for a runtime solution

Comment: less can run in the browser via `less.js`

Answer (score 6):

Benjamin's suggestion was one of my suggestions. The other less known trick is that you can set a disabled property on a stylesheet and that will disable that style sheet

Say you have two stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blue-theme.css" id="blue-theme"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="red-theme.css" id="red-theme"/>
```

You can easily enable just one of them

```
function setTheme(theme) {
    var themes = ["blue-theme", "red-theme"];
    for (var i=0; i < themes.length; i++) {

      var styleSheet = document.getElementById(themes[i]);
      if (themes[i] == theme) {
        styleSheet.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else {
        styleSheet.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      }      
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do so your site will be blinking in Chrome while switching themes. Proper way of such switching is shown here: http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/switch-alternate-css-styles.shtml (don't forget to add 'title' attribute to 'link' element. Without it trick will not work in Chrome).

Comment: @StanislavBerkov The link you provided actually uses the same technique in https://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml because the `<meta>` based approach isn't really well supported. From the link you provided: `The next chapter, on using JavaScript to change the style sheet dynamically, will provide a way to deal with these shortcomings.`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).  A more complicated way, but one that could be more useful if you plan to do this alot, would be to have your css file handled by php or asp.net (depending on your platform) and use code to output the css (making sure to output the proper headers for a CSS file).