# How To switch between themes?

Tags: php

I want to change CSS file due the user choice in select list :

```
<select>
<option>light</option>
<option>dark</option>
</select>
```

so when chosen light the css file will be light.css and when Dark so dark.css
And save this coice in the cookies or whatever .
Thanks !

Comment: [What have  you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Use JavaScript to alternate between two external stylesheets. Come back with a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946593/how-to-change-and-maintain-multiple-color-themes-at-runtime-with-css/9946764#9946764

Comment: HI Arthur, Its usually best to use stackoverflow to ask a question if you get stuck doing something giving clear examples of your code and explain what you have already tried to resolve the issue.  Your current question seems to be askign someone here to write the solution for you which isnt the purpose of stackoverflow.  To point you in the right direction your going to have to google around a bit and look for a css switcher jquery/javascript.  trying to tell you how to build the entire solution would take ages.

Comment: I know, I just dont know how to start ! Thats all I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a disabled property on a stylesheet and that will disable that style sheet

Say you have two stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="light-theme.css" id="light-theme"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dark-theme.css" id="dark-theme"/>
```

You can easily enable just one of them

```
function setTheme(theme) {
    var themes = ["light-theme", "dark-theme"];
    for (var i=0; i < themes.length; i++) {

      var styleSheet = document.getElementById(themes[i]);
      if (themes[i] == theme) {
        styleSheet.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else {
        styleSheet.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      }      
    }
}
```

See [How to change and maintain multiple color themes at runtime with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946593/how-to-change-and-maintain-multiple-color-themes-at-runtime-with-css/9946764#9946764)

You'd still need to save it to a cookie, you can ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to hook on the `onchange` event of the `select` element, and use it to set a theme-specific class on your `<body>` element, causing other styles to apply from your stylesheet. Alternatively you could destroy a stylesheet and reload one dynamically, but that's a more advanced topic.

Since you tagged this question [php](/questions/tagged/php) it's also worth mentioning that usually you just do a postback to the server for this, change some session/cookie data there, and based on that generate another `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of your templates.

Both options mentioned are a valid approach to the issue.